# Looking for an anthology book containing a story about an alien named Ineed by a little girl

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, books

One of the stories I am sure was called The Road and another was about a mysterious alien that a young girl named Ineed and her mother kept correcting it to Enid. I read it in the 70's or early 80's.

This book was an anthology book containing works by multiple authors, possibly a collection of short stories that had something to do with Isaac Asimov(?)

I recall the front cover displayed a man and some very odd looking plant-life (alien one presumes) against a pale blue background.

Comment: ..."A book of short stories by Isaac Asimov written by other authors" is rather confusing. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @MeatTrademark - "...edited by Asimov,", I assume OP means.

Comment: @Valorum I would likewise assume. As someone who's been around here way more than I, :) what do you think of the edit to the title without the OP's explicit clarification?

Comment: @Lexible - I'd be happier if they confirmed it since the edit changes the meaning of the post (although admittedly it also changes it from incoherent to coherent)

Comment: @Valorum Thank you! Posted a [question on meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12145/should-a-meaningful-edit-in-the-asbence-of-op-input-be-rolled-back) about this.

Comment: I am sorry ... I don't have a lot of info ...just my memories of a book that was, I am pretty sure,  a collection  of short stories.... That had something to do with Isaac Asimov.  I recall the front cover displayed a man and some very odd looking plant life ...alien one presumed... On a pale blue background heh ... Sorry ..not much help there. But I would be massively grateful for any and all your help x

Comment: @Eyeball - Don't forget that you can [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/197125/edit) your own question. I've taken the liberty of adding the info in for you this time :-)

Answer (score 10):

> another was about a mysterious alien that a young girl named Ineed and her mother kept correcting it to Enid.

I have no idea about Asimov , but I hazard to guess that the story you are referencing above is "[At the Bottom of the Garden](https://www.mail-archive.com/scifinoir2@yahoogroups.com/msg02044.html)" by David Campton. The story was first published in *Armada Sci Fi* 1 in 1975, and subsequently collected in several anthologies.

"At the Bottom of the Garden" was ***creepy as creepy gets***. There is indeed a young girl, she indeed has a friend named Ineed who is... uh... not from around these parts, and her distracted mother indeed corrects her about many things including calling her friend "Enid". The story opens with the memorable line

> "MUMMY, why has Ineed got furry teeth?"

*[SHUDDER]*

- None of the anthologies featuring this story that are listed on [ISFD](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?79212) were edited by Isaac Asimov, nor did he contribute to them.
- None of the anthologies listed contains a story titled "The Road".

Comment: The title is an allusion the first line of Rose Fyleman's poem "Fairies": http://www.theotherpages.org/poems/fyleman.html

Comment: Oh yes!! Furry teeth!!!! That's it!!! So... What collection did this story appear in please?

Comment: Btw this site is amazing!! Thanks for all your input! :D (y)

Comment: @Eyeball There were *several* collections. Follow the blue ISFD link at the bottom of my answer to see them. Also: if my answer serves you well, feel free to up vote (clicking the up-arrow to the top left of my answer, and if you feel I nailed it, please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark there.

Comment: This cover has a man running from an alien-looking plant; https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91fKdnU9nvL.jpg

Comment: That's a good story. Wish I read it yesterday.

Comment: The version of this story that was published in SF-1 had a much nicer ending than the one in the horror anthologies.  Ineed was still weird though.

Comment: @PastychomperthanksMonica Oh! That's too bad. :) Now I am curious.

Comment: @Lexible I was surprised when I read the version linked in your answer :) I can't find the other ending anywhere online, so here's a brief spoiler from memory:  At the point where the parents found Ineed "working" on their daughter, instead of scaring her off and burying the dismembered body they ran back to the house and called the police.  When they returned they found the girl in one piece and playing on the grass, with straightened teeth and no longer needing glasses, and no memory of anyone named Enid or Ineed.  Then the cops took the parents inside for a long talk.

Answer (score 1):

The anthology [*SF1*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2776049-sf-1) (edited by Richard Davis) had pale blue cover depicting the protagonist from one story running towards the reader.

There was also a story about 4 sisters in a junior school who were essentially the same Being. The one in the lowest class wouldn't say "The Cat sat on the mat" because where she came from the cats were 10 feet tall.

There was one story about a cosmo-botanist on an unexplored supposedly desert planet who discovers a hitherto undetected lifeforms.

[image]

Comment: Just found the book. Thanks. It's called SF1. Thanks so much for posting!

Comment: Are you the original poster? If so, you should [merge your accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) and accept Lexible's answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].